# Make html checkbox checked and non editable

Tags: html

I have an HTML form, with a few input Checkboxes. I need two of these to be preselected and  non edidtable. I have tried the "checked" & "disabled" together, but the disabled input is not include in form submit. Is there any other way of doing it ? I want the checkbox to be checked and non editable and its value to be submitted on form submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If checked and disabled gives you the look that you want, then add some hidden form fields that submit the data you need.

Comment: I was literally just about to say that

Comment: I was in the middle of typing this same answer. xD

Answer (score 1):

I have one workaround for your problem.

You can store checked checkbox value in hidden field and access the hidden field on form submit.

On html side :

Make checkbox selected and disabled. at the same time save selected checkbox value in hidden field as comma separated string.

On serevr side:
Get value out of comma separeted  string as string array and save value of array in database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way if you are prefer to use script. You didn't mention in your question whether you are able to use it. I hope this would help you at least a bit.. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.required-checkbox').each(function(index, value){
                    $(value).change(function(){
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" class="required-checkbox" checked />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" class="required-checkbox" checked />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox"  />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the "disabled" state on those inputs during the *form submit event*.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var disabledInputs = $(this).find(':input:disabled');
    disabledInputs.removeAttr('disabled');
    return true;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
<style>
.read_only {
    pointer-events: none;

}
 </style>
```

and apply this class to any input form field even checkbox and it works fine, and the checkbox is colored not disabled

Answer (score -1):

```
$(":checked").on('click',function(){   //select those element which you want to make preselect and non editable...
 $(this).attr("checked","checked");
});
```

You don't need to disable it...